# Java - Method changes value of variable in JTable (refresh not working)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable with a variable inside one of the cells. When Button is clicked the variable changes but nothing changes in JTable.
Here is my simple example code:

```
public class Test extends JPanel {
static String var = "One";
Object rowData[][] = { { var, "Two", "Three" },
    { "Four", "Five", "Six" } };
Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
static JTable table;

static DefaultTableModel tableModel;
JButton button = new JButton("Refresh");
public Test(){
    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
    table = new JTable(tableModel);
    add(table);
    button.addActionListener(new Action());
    add(button);
}
private static class Action implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        var = "ONE";
        System.out.println(var);
        String[] data = {"ciao"};
        tableModel.fireTableStructureChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Can someone help me please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never change your tableModel's data at all, so it makes sense that the JTable never changes. Perhaps you want to call `setValueAt(...)` on the model to change the value held by one of its cells. After you do that, there's no need to call `fireXxxx(...)` on the model since this is (and should be) called *internally* by the model itself.

Ah, I see what you've done. You are thinking that by changing the String that `var` refers to, the JTable's data will magically change, but that's magical thinking as all you're doing is changing the object that the `var` variable refers to and you're having absolutely no effect on the String object that it referred to previously and that is being displayed in the JTable. This issue gets to a core concept of Java's OOP model, that of the difference between objects and reference variables. Changing a variable reference has no effect on the object it refers to. Again, call `setValueAt(...)` on your model and your problem is solved.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test extends JPanel {
   static String var = "One";
   Object rowData[][] = { { var, "Two", "Three" }, { "Four", "Five", "Six" } };
   Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
   JTable table;

   DefaultTableModel tableModel;
   JButton button = new JButton("Refresh");

   public Test() {
      tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
      table = new JTable(tableModel);
      add(table);
      button.addActionListener(new Action());
      add(button);
   }

   private class Action implements ActionListener {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String var2 = "ONE";
         System.out.println(var2);
         // String[] data = { "ciao" };
         // tableModel.fireTableStructureChanged();

         tableModel.setValueAt(var2, 0, 0);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Test());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```